# How to compare models using anova in rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2, anova

In R, it is possible to compare two fitted models say fit1 and fit2 by using the command `anova(fit1,fit2)`.

However, if we try to do this similarly using the interface Rpy2, it always gives an error. The anova for a single model, say anova(fit1) can be computed through Rpy2.

The error that occurs while using two is:

```
no method for coercing this S4 class into a vector.
```

So, I wanted to know how this problem can be rectified and how can I compare the two fitted models in rpy2?

Answer (score 1):

You need these headings

```
 import rpy2.robjects as robjects
 from rpy2.robjects import DataFrame, Formula
```

then, This has worked for me:

```
formula = Formula('responsev ~ predictorv')
formula2 = Formula('responsev ~ predictorv2')
dataf = DataFrame({'responsev': robjects.IntVector(Y), \
               'predictorv': robjects.IntVector(X),\
                                'predictorv2': robjects.IntVector(X2)})

fit=robjects.r.lm(formula=formula, data=dataf)
fit2=robjects.r.lm(formula=formula2, data=dataf)

a=robjects.r.anova(fit,fit2)
```

You'll still need to figure out how to handle `a` but that should be minor.

Hope it helps!

Comment: fmla=Formula('Protein~Time+Group+Age+Gender+(1|PatientID)') ;fmla2=Formula('Protein~Group+Age+Gender+(1|PatientID)');
fit1=robjects.r.lmer(formula=fmla, data=dataf,REML='FALSE');
fit2=r.lmer(formula=fmla2, data=dataf,REML='FALSE') ;a=robjects.r.anova(fit1,fit2);
But, it still gives the same error: no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Comment: It works if you use lm. But the error is given on using lmer. I need to use lmer as I am trying to do a mixed effect model. So, is there any other command that needs to be given for it.

Comment: you probably need to import your library or something of the sort. Did you try that?